# Read file with Python while passing arguments

Tags: python-3.x, string

I'm trying to read a file with this argument `{year}` inside it.

Inside this file there is this string:
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR = {year}`

I'd like to read this file with `Python` `f-strings` to use the query after.

The expected result looks like this:
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR = 2019`

I tried this:

```
year = 2019
with open("test.sql") as query_file:
     query = query_file.read()
print(query)
```

But the output was `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR = {year}` instead of `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR = 2019`

I have no idea how I can put the `year` variable to replace the `{year}` inside the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to replace the `{year}`.

f-strings are literals and must be an expression. Python will not replace data in string, just because there is a variable of the same name in the bracket notation.

```py
query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR = {year}'
query.format(year=2019)
```

---

**Edit:**
To replace values in a SQL query it's better and more secure to use prepared statements like:

```
c = db.cursor()
year = 2019
c.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR = %s;", (year,))
```

See also the [examples of `MySQLdb`](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#some-examples)